# htaccess rewrite url to hide variable

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My knowledge of htaccess is pretty limited, so please be gentle...
I have a php page that displays an article, based on a variable passed through the url. For each article, I want the url to be changed to the article title, but I can't lose the article id being passed to the page...

So, for ...
www.somesite.com/news/article?id=4
... I can change it to ...
www.somesite.com/news/here-is-the-article-title

Or for 
www.somesite.com/news/article?id=7
... I can change it to ...
www.somesite.com/news/some-other-title-that-I-choose

Bascially, I want the content for "article?id=4" to be shown on the page, but the URL to read "here-is-the-article-title". Is this even possible using htaccess? Or is there a similar solution?  I know that I'll probably have to rewrite EACH url, and I'm fine with that.

I have some standard htaccess code I use...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

 # enable the rewrite engine
  RewriteEngine On
  # Set your root directory
  RewriteBase /

  # remove the .php extension
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
  RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

  # remove index and reference the directory
  RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

  # remove trailing slash if not a directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

  # forward request to html file, **but don't redirect (bot friendly)**
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
  RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

# Disable Directory Browsing
  Options -Indexes

# Protect htaccess File
  <files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
  satisfy all
  </files>
```

Basic REDIRECT doesn't work, since I lose the article id.

Comment: This would only be possible directly and completely in .htaccess, if you explicitly wrote a rule for every single case. Otherwise, how is your server supposed to know that `here-is-the-article-title` is supposed to translate to id 4, and `some-other-title-that-I-choose` represents item 7 …? The way this is done is that you pass the actual title string on to your script as parameter, and the script then uses that to search for the appropriate record in the database.

Comment: I don't mind writing a rule for every single case ... I just don't know how to do this using htaccess.

Comment: But you have understood the basic principle of how RewriteRules work, yes? (If not, you should make an effort to inform yourself on that first of all.) Since you won’t be doing any pattern matching, but are looking to match a static path 1:1, you won’t need that much regex knowledge; basically only which characters with a special meaning would have to be escaped.